# Is there a way we can archive calendar items in Exchange Online?

Tags: exchange-server, office365, archive, office365api, hybrid

My question is specific to Exchange Online not Exchange server. I am not able to find any document online stating if Contacts & Calendars can be moved to In-Place Archive mailbox on Exchange Online. 
It would be great if you can help me with the steps, if this is possible.
Also, is there a way to access them through Office365 APIs.

Additionally, it would be great to know if this can be done in Hybrid setups, where the primary mailbox is on-premise and archive mailbox is on Exchange Online.

Answer (score 0):

> > My question is specific to Exchange Online not Exchange server. I am not able to find any document online stating if Contacts & Calendars can be moved to In-Place Archive mailbox

From a Technical point of view you can move any item you like into an In-Place archive, the Archive policies and the Managed Folder Agent however won't move them for reason that Contact are ageless and Calendar appointment if they are recurring shouldn't need archiving. EWS has an ArchiveItem operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj219964(v=exchg.150).aspx which make the move between store pretty easy. But you should be able to do the same thing with a Move in the REST api.

AFAIK None of the API methods apart from MAPI will work in Hybrid you'll need to rely on a export/import with the other API's